# Calculating 0,1 in two different columns in R

Tags: r, count

I have a data (DAT) of ~30,000 subjects with several columns in the form of 0,1 and a 'Group' variable e.g.,

[image]

I want to count how many subjects in group '2' are 1 in V1 and V5. How do I do it in R command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is called `df`, you can use

```
with(df, sum(Group == 2 & V1 == 1 & V5 == 1))
```

Since you only have 0 and 1 values in `V1` and `V5` columns, you can also do

```
sum(unlist(df[df$Group == 2, c("V1", "V5")]))
```